# Compute the hundreds digit of an arbitrary real number

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

How would I convert this number (42519.36) to a whole real number (5)?

42519.36 = 5

What is the most efficient way in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would this number result in 5?

Comment: what is the relationship between the two numbers?

Comment: Per the title, I believe the result is `5` because that is the value in the 'hundreds place' for `42519.36`.

Comment: If this is a homework, use the *homework* tag.

Comment: It looks like he/she wants to extract-out the hundred's place digit. Example 12345 would be 3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the remainder operator:

```
int hundredDigit=(int)Math.Abs(number/100%10)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
(x % 1000 - x % 100) / 100
```

Comment: You'll need to add `Abs` if you want to support negative numbers. I'd also cast to int afterwards, since a digit is an integer for me.